# How to check the applicability of a Microsoft patch

Tags: windows, powershell, patch

**Environment:**

I work in a lab that tests software against multiple domain configurations.  I currently have 8 domains with no cross-domain trust.  They each have a WSUS server that talks to our primary NOC WSUS Server.  Other than talking to the primary WSUS server, there is no communication from one domain to the other.  I cannot change GPO settings or install any software that isn't already installed.  The domains range from Windows XP with Server 2003 to Windows 7 with Server 2008.  Each domain has anywhere between 8-20 servers and 3-5 workstations.

I have a machine that can talk to each of the servers in all of the domains, and can also talk to the primary WSUS server. I primary work with PowerShell, but I'm not opposed to another language if it makes what I'm trying to do easier. I have PowerShell 2.0 installed, but I can easily installed PowerShell 3.0 if needed.

**Scenario:**

I am charged with checking if patches have been installed on each of the servers.  This testing cannot rely on WSUS's built in reporting tools, per requirements I cannot change.  I would receive a list of patches, and I need to check each server to see if the patches are installed.  Since the patches can be anything from Windows XP to Server 2008, I also need to check if the patch is applicable to the server itself.  I have tried to use `PoshWSUS` to check for applicability, but I cannot get a connection to the Primary WSUS server because of either IIS rules or a Firewall rule.  I have search online, and followed several guides, but this WSUS's setup is very customized, and I can only do so much to the server itself.

**Example:**

I have the following Patches:

```
KB2604092
KB2676562
KB2686509
```

I want to check the following server:

```
DC01: A Windows Server 2008 Domain Controller
```

I am currently using the following PowerShell command to test if they are installed:

```
Get-HotFix -ID "KB2604092","KB2676562","KB2686509" -ComputerName DC01
```

This command shows the following patches are installed:

```
KB2676562
KB2686509
```

Leaving the following uninstalled:

```
KB2604092
```

This correctly tells me that `KB2676562` and `KB2686509` are installed, but it doesn't tell me if `KB2604092` missing, or not applicable.

What I am stuck on is how to verify that `KB2604092` is not applicable to DC01.  I can easily search Microsoft's site to verify it is only for Windows Server 2003 or Windows XP, but how can I check it's applicability via a script.  I would love to find a way to scrap the Microsoft KB article for the data, but I don't know how to pull the required information from the web page.  I assume there has to be a check within WSUS to check applicability, but I don't know where to look for something like that.

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention, I have no control over what patches are approved, that is done by an outside company.

Comment: Is this just for security patches, or all possible patches?

Comment: @zdan It is primarily for security patches, but there is the possibility of any Microsoft patch coming down the pipe.

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, it is also possible to use the Windows Update API to bypass the WSUS server and scan against Microsoft Update directly.  However the clients do need internet access for this to work.  Another option (for security updates only) is an offline scan using `wsusscn2.cab`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well for security patches, Microsoft publishes a a spreadsheet that lists the all security bulletins since 1998. You can download from [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/). [(Direct link to spreadsheet)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=245778)

You could then parse that spreadsheet (if you convert it to a CSV file, that would be easy to parse in powershell). It gives you all the information you are asking about.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know about that spreadsheet.  When I get to work on Monday, I'll see what I can do with it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only interested in whether the update is applicable to the corresponding operating system, [IUpdate.ProductTitles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.updateservices.administration.iupdate.producttitles%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should give you the information you need.

There are more complicated cases, such as where an update is applicable only if a certain system component is installed.  I don't think there's any way to handle those cases automatically.